# How do I get the top and bottom bar like this?

Tags: html, css

Hey guys.. Check out the fading grey on top of the page and the grey for the footer here http://www.alcatel-lucent.com/wps/portal/BellLabs .. How do i get this using css... I tried using

```
#bgtop{
background-image:url('bg_top.JPG');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
margin-top:auto;
}
```

But this doesnt work.. Please help

Comment: you can always see the source of this site and learn how to do it

Comment: This is what alcatel is using: `background: white url(http://www.alcatel-lucent.com/wps/themes/html/ExternalVGAMain/images/menu-one-button-normal.jpg) repeat-x 50% 0%;` 

If you have problems like this, it would be very helpful with more code. Perhaps you could create an example in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying a height

```
#bgtop{
background-image:url('bg_top.JPG');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
margin-top:auto;
height: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the html the background image you want with repeat-x, it should work that way.